# How to overwrite a library (ex., path) in Angular with the mocked library I have created for testing?

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, testbed

I am working on an Angular application that runs in Electron. However, we use cypress for E2E testing, and therefore I have mocked all the dependencies of Electron. So, we want the mocks to be used only when testing (to allow the app to be compiled in web) and not in the production code. Before I had created mocks in the prod code, but now I have to remove those from there. For example, I have the 'path' library which has to be replaced with the mocked one as soon as I run the test command. Could you please help me to solve that problem?

Comment: Did you have a look to the angular.json config ? You may specify different configs for dev, prod, and tests. You should be able to replace some import paths.

Comment: Mocking libraries is apparently going very deep because those libs are native of nodeJs. Therefore, I thought a better way would be to mock the files/services itself and replace the original files with the mocked ones on angular.json.

"fileReplacements": [
{
      "replace": "myService",
      "with": "myServiceMock"
}],

However, so far it does not give any result. Any idea why?

Comment: fileReplacements expects a file path, not a Class name. Did you use a file path ?

Comment: I found that replacing libraries is very complex and I decided to rather replace the services that use these libraries with the mocked services. This is why I decided to go with the fileReplacement. However, it is not making the replacement even though the paths are correct.

"fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "path1/project-upload-factory.service.ts",
                                    "with": "path1/project-upload-factory.service.mock.ts"
                                }
                            ],